# Remove items from list stored in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, nlp

I have a DataFrame that contains some (text-) cleaned ads in one column and some very basic description of the same ads in one other column. I also have term frequencies stored in a dictionary in 'keyword':frequency format.

Task would be to purge all terms from the list in the `df` that falls below a certain cutpoint level of frequency.

```
import pandas as pd

adset = {"ID": ["(1483785165, 2009)", "(1538280431, 2010)", "(1795044103, 2010)"],
        "Body":[['price', '#', 'bedrooms', '#', 'bathrooms', '#', 'garage'],['cindy', 'lavender', 'mid', 'state', 'realty'],['upgrades', 'galore', 'perfectly', 'maintained', 'home', 'formals']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(adset)

keyword_dict={}
for row in data['Body']:
    for word in row:
        if word in keyword_dict:
            keyword_dict[word]+=1
        else:
            keyword_dict[word]=1
```

And here is where I got stuck:

```
def remove_sparse_words_from_df(df, term_freq, cutoff=1):
    for row in df['Body']:
        for word in row:
            if term_freq[word]<=cutoff:
    
    return df
```

My whole approach might be off - performance is a huge issue, the `df` has about 350k rows and the lists in the "Body" column might contain words ranging in number from a few hundred to few thousands. The reason for storing all the data in pandas `df` instead of lists is that I would like to keep the ID column, so I could later connect my data to some other analysis I've already done on the ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

1. use `explode` to split the list to individual rows
2. `groupby` and `transform` to get the count of the keyword in the dataframe and keep only rows where the "count" is greater than the cutoff
3. `groupby` and `agg` to get the original DataFrame structure.

```
cutoff = 1

df = df.explode("Body")
output = df.loc[df.groupby("Body")["ID"].transform("size").gt(1)].groupby("ID").agg(list)

>>> output
                         Body
ID                           
(1483785165, 2009)  [#, #, #]
```

Note: In your example "#" is the only "word" that occurs more than once.

Comment: Hi! Much thanks for the answer, i can't understand completely whats going on, but that probably only means there's a lot to learn :)

Your code seems to run fine on my df in this example, but not on the real one :| The code runs but leaves the db intact even if i change gt(1) to gt(10). 

I did the best to perfectly imitate my data in the example above, seems like i failed tho.

Could you please look at some real data I use? I cant seem to spot the difference... 

https://pastebin.com/g25bHCC7